# R keep rows of matrix if available in other matrix omitting NAs

Tags: r, matrix, comparison, matching

I cannot find an efficient way of only keeping the rows in matrix m1 if the row is contained in a row of matrix m2. Matrix m2 can contain NA's which don't have to match with the row of matrix m1. See the following example:

```
m1 = matrix(c(1:6), ncol=2, byrow = T)
m2 = matrix(c(NA, 4, NA, 2), ncol=2, byrow=T)
```

After running the code m1 one should be:

> [image]

Matrix m1 keeps row 1 because column 2 of m1 matches column 2 in m2 (NA must be omitted). Furthermore, matrix m1 keeps row 2 since column 2 of m1 matches to column 1 in m2. 
Ideally it shouldn't be solved with loops in order to keep performance high. It has to run for large matrices.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, maybe the following will do.

```
inx <- m1[, 1] %in% m2[, 1] | m1[, 2] %in% m2[, 2]
m1[inx, ]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```